# Setting up an email system from my google spreadsheet. I have everything else working except for adding an image into the body

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

I'm trying to add an image into the body of the emails. I've been able to get everything else working fine besides the image part. The images I'm trying to use are in the "M Column".

What do I need to add to get the value from the "M Column" and put it into the body of the emails?
-code is provided below

Thanks in advance. Everything I've tried has failed so I just removed everything I attempted and went to what I originally had before I decided to add images to the emails.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 15;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 15);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4];
    var message = row[10];
    var subject = "Subject Test";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

```
[error message][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwAJG.png
```

Comment: About `get the value from the "M Column"`, what value is put to the column "M"? In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an email which contains `images`, you could use one of the following options:

- **If your images are stored as `urls` in your Spreadsheet**

The following code snippet is used to create the attachment containing the image gathered from a `url` stored in your Spreadsheet.

```
  var imageUrl = sheet.getRange("YOUR_RANGE_FOR_THE_IMAGE").getValue(); 
  var imageBody = "<img src='cid:myImage'>";
  var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl)
                           .getBlob()
                           .setName("imageBlob");
  var message = row[10];
  var subject = "Subject Test";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress, 
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message +"<br/><br/>"+ imageBody,
    inlineImages:{
      myImage: imageBlob
      }
  });
```

The above code snippet uses `InlineImages` in order to attach the image as an attachment into the email you want to send.

- **If your images are stored in drive and you have their file `ids`**

The following code snippet is used to create the attachment containing the image gathered from the `id` of the file which is stored in Drive.

```
  var imageId = sheet.getRange("YOUR_RANGE_FOR_THE_IMAGE").getValue(); 
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById(imageId);
  var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob('', 'image/jpeg');

  var message = row[10];
  var subject = "Subject Test";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress, 
    subject: subject, 
    body: message,
    attachments: [image.getAs(MimeType.JPEG), imageBlob]
  });
```

- **If your images are stored `inside a cell` and/or as `overgrid images`**

Unfortunately, Google Sheets doesn't have the capacity to return the blob of an image, only a reference to the image which means that you cannot retrieve the images and attach them afterwards in an e-mail using Google Apps Script.

In this case, an alternative would be to use the `=IMAGE()` function to insert the **images in a cell** and afterwards you can retrieve them by using the [Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).

**Reference**

- [MailApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app);
- [Sheets Class Apps Script getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation);
- [DrivApp Class Apps Script getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid);
- [Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference);
- [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).

Comment: - What would my range for the image be if I'm using an image from my drive?
- Also, do i have to change anything in this part of the code? // var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob('', 'image/jpeg'); //

Comment: @JordanTaylor, it’s the range in which you stored the **id** of the file in Spreadsheet. So for example, if your **id** is stored in the **M1**, you will have to input “M1” there.

Comment: Whatever I just did, did not work and now I can't get the original code I had working. I'll try and explain this the best I can. I have an email list that I need to send out individual personalized emails too, each containing a subject, body text and image. My setup is as follows. I have a list of emails in Column F2:F. I have text for each specific email address in Column O2:O. My Google Drive Image ID is in column N2:N. The Subject for each email will say the same thing. "Subject Test".

Comment: @JordanTaylor, the second option should work just fine for your situation then. What do you mean by “did not work”? Did you get any error messages? Did you set the ranged accordingly? Cheers!

Comment: I added a link with a picture of what I'm working with. Appreciate all the help so far.

Comment: @JordanTaylor, the error is at the `var imageUrl = sheet.getRange("M1:M").getValue();`. You are using a whole range but you are trying to get only one image. It should be `"M1"` instead of `"M1:M"`.

Comment: Still having the same issue. Turns out it was supposed to be ("N2") anyway but still have the same error message as before. Am I supposed to put the entire shareable link from the image or just the ID code at the end in cell N2?

Comment: @JordanTaylor, since the method used is `getFileById()` you should input the ID of the file. I suggest you take a look at the documenation for Apps Script as well, as I edited my answer providing more links that can be of help to you. Cheers!

Comment: I have only the ID in N2 and getting same error message. Losing my mind over here. ~~~~~ Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getAs on object DriveApp.File. (line 19, file "Code") ~~~~~

Comment: @JordanTaylor, how are you retrieving the id of the file that you have in your Spreadsheet? Do you have permissions for accessing this file?